# Loading xml data into ndbunit

Tags: c#, load, ndbunit

I am having problem loading the testdata.xml into ndbunit,
I followed http://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/wiki/QuickStartGuide,
but the test data is not loaded when I run my unit test in NUnit.

Is there any gotcha that I am not aware of ?

Comment: post a test-case that demonstrates the issue to the NDbUnit issues wiki at http://code.google.com/p/ndbunit that includes the DDL to create the tables as they exist in your database, the XSD + XML you are using, and the code from your unit test and we can see what e can do once we have these details!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Then I noticed that my xml file did not have the namespace in it
i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

<NewDataSet>
```

instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet 
        xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Database.xsd" >
```

Once I put the namespace in, my tests were happy again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found that you can't change the namespace to something else.  As of this writing the namespace is hardcoded to be `http://tempuri.org` in the NDbUnit source.

Comment: Did you specify a 'NewDataSet' element type in the xsd file?